# is there any method to do same function as for loop without actually using the forloop?

Tags: batch-file

Sample for loop is given below. How to achieve same function without using for loop.

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 100) do echo %x
```

Comment: Could you also clarify why you want to avoid a `for` loop? That might add value to your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
:loop
set /a count+=1
echo %count%
if %count% neq 100 goto:loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set /a a=1
:label
echo %a%
set /a a+=1
if %a%' EQU 100' (goto :outOfLoop)
goto :label
:outOfLoop
echo done!
```